# How would a mute wizard cast spells?

Tags: harry-potter

You need to say the words to cast a spell. How would a deaf or mute wizard/witch do that?

Comment: There are non-verbal spells. http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Nonverbal_spell

Comment: They would probably be specially trained in non-verbal spells right from their first year at school.

Comment: Thanks, I'm grabbing those reputation points. ;) But I already knew about it, I'm just wording it a bit more nicely.

Comment: The real question is how a blind witch/wizard would cast spells or duel. Where would they point their wands?

Comment: Hmm. Unless the muteness was the result of dark magic, it would simply be cured magically

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In later years at school, wizards learn how to use spells without speaking them out loud. This is often done if they want to get an advantage over their opponent by giving them less time to react, but it could also be used in this case.

Unspoken spells are harder to do than spoken ones, but if it's your only option to cast them, you'll have to learn them from the first year on. You'd probably get into performing magic slower than most of the others, but since it's easier for young children to learn something new, you would probably catch up with the others pretty quickly.

More information [here](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Nonverbal_spell) ([archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20170929080903/http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Nonverbal_spell), original linked by [Jack B Nimble](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1148/jack-b-nimble) in a comment to the question)

Comment: 'This is often done if they want to get an advantage over their opponent'

True although in the case of Severus he could at least with Harry parry his curses because of knowing what Harry was about to cast due to legilimency (but then he was a far better wizard than Harry and Harry was particularly bad about Occlumency). Otoh there are some spells that are meant to be cast non-verbally e.g. some of Severus's inventions like Levicorpus. That last real paragraph is interesting: children do tend to learn quicker though I'm not sure the - what I'll call - cut off age is.

Comment: There is no clear line. You don't suddenly learn slower from a certain age on, it's a gradual process. Maybe reverse exponential.

Comment: I was referring to the stages one develops as; beta and whatever other stages there are (and maybe beta isn't one of them - I don't recall immediately but I think you know what I mean). So I'm actually saying the same thing as you only maybe more scientifically (or it would be if I remembered the names of the stages!).