# Are non-verbal spells in Harry Potter silent or just quiet?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-theory

After a few too many cases in the last two books where someone is said to have "muttered" a spell, I've lost track of how non-verbal spells work.

**Are they absolutely silent, or just quiet?**

Comment: The question of mute wizards is dealt with here; [How would a mute wizard cast spells?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/170913/how-would-a-mute-wizard-cast-spells)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Silent (if done properly).

> Harry frequently looked over at his classmates in the common room or at mealtimes to see them purple in the face and straining as though they had overdosed on U-No-Poo; but he knew that they were really struggling to make spells work **without saying incantations aloud**.
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince</sup></sub>

and

> Pointing his wand at nothing in particular, he gave it an upward flick
> and said Levicorpus! **inside his head.**
>
> ‘Aaaaaaaargh!’
>
> There was a flash of light and the room was full of voices: everyone
> had woken up as Ron had let out a yell.
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince</sup></sub>